# remove clip on context in quartz 2d

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, quartz-2d

I have drawn a path to my context with an arc, set that as a clip, and drawn an image into that clip.

```
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lineStartPoint.x, lineStartPoint.y);
CGContextAddArc(context, lineStartPoint.x, lineStartPoint.y, 105, toAngle*M_PI,fromAngle*M_PI , 1);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, toLinePoint.x, toLinePoint.y);
CGContextClip(context);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientfill.png"] drawInRect:[self bounds]];
```

This works perfectly, as shown in this image

[image: context clipping]

My problem is that in the bottom of that gradient I have drawn a circle that I want to exist outside of the clip, it should look like this

[image]

How do I get my context to stop clipping so that I can have that circle outside of the clip?

My code for drawing the circle is

```
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGRect toHandleRect = CGRectMake(toLinePoint.x-5, toLinePoint.y-5, 10, 10);    
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, toHandleRect);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGPathRelease(path);
```

I want the user to be able to drag the little circle to anywhere in that view.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can issue a CGContextSaveGState + CGContextRestoreGState pair as in the following example:

```
// Saves the context including the current clipping region.
CGContextSaveGState(context);

// Build you clip region and do some drawing
CGContextBeginPath(context);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, lineStartPoint.x, lineStartPoint.y);
CGContextAddArc(context, lineStartPoint.x, lineStartPoint.y, 105, toAngle*M_PI,fromAngle*M_PI , 1);
CGContextMoveToPoint(context, toLinePoint.x, toLinePoint.y);
CGContextClip(context);

[[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientfill.png"] drawInRect:[self bounds]];

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGRect toHandleRect = CGRectMake(toLinePoint.x-5, toLinePoint.y-5, 10, 10);    
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, toHandleRect);
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGPathRelease(path);

// Restore the original state
CGContextRestoreGState(context);
```

Comment: Fantastic, thanks very much!

To get the circle outside of the clip area, I just moved the CGContextRestoreGState() to before I add the path to the context.